# Jquery button click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and want to put in a submenu within the page. However, can not get the jquery to recognize the button click.

```
<div  class="navbar navbar-default visible-xs" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button id="sideMenuBtn" type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-toggle="offcanvas" data-                                                       target=".sidebar-nav">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Project Name</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation" >
        <hr />
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
     $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

If I change the first line of the code to `<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">` it works fine. But I dont want it fixed to top.

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Create a fiddle please http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You know you didn't close the document ready function properly ?

Comment: Not sure if it is just a typo, but one of your button declartions is missing '>' (see sideMenuBtn)

Comment: And it works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/bZfH8/

Comment: });  is how it should be closed.  It is right in my document, just forgot to type it in.

Comment: If I change the first line of the html code to:
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
then it works fine.  But I dont want it to be fixed to top.

Comment: so the button works but is just not positionned as intended? Did you try to console.log() something inside the button's click event?

Comment: Sorry did'nt explain myself well.  If I take out the navbar-fixed-top of the first line of code then it does not work at all..  Button is position correctly, but does not work unless navbar-fixed-top class is added. The interesting thing is I can put my code on jsfiddle it works fine there. but not in my local development environment which is VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Thank you to everyone who commented.  The answer was really simple.  I just changed the first line of code to  `<div class="navbar navbar-default visible-xs" role="navigation" style="z-index:1000">`  Apparently something was covering the button. when I raised the z-index, problem disappeared.